HTTPExchange - Using a SpringBoot Pageable parameter support available?
The docs for reference : HttpInterface/Exchange Spring Boot REST Clients
I was wondering if there was, or if not plans, to be able to use SpringBoot's Pageable interface in @HttpExchange methods.
It seems at the moment it is not possible so when proxying a request from one SpringBoot app via a pageable controller with Spring Pageable it seems the docs show that it can not then be proxied to a second spring boot app with a pageable argument?

Currently, using Pageable directly with @HttpExchange in Spring Boot REST clients isn't supported. The Pageable interface relies on Spring MVC’s method argument resolvers, which aren’t directly compatible with @HttpExchange. As a result, if you’re proxying requests between two Spring Boot applications where one endpoint uses Pageable, it won't translate automatically through @HttpExchange.
However, you can work around this limitation by manually adding pagination parameters (page, size, sort) as query parameters in the @HttpExchange method, then map these parameters to a Pageable in the receiving service.
1.Proxy Client Configuration: Define the query parameters as standard
@HttpExchange("/endpoint")
public List<YourResponseType> proxyRequest(
    @RequestParam int page, 
    @RequestParam int size, 
    @RequestParam List<String> sort);

